# Find process causing IO wait time

Tags: linux, centos, process, multi-core

mpstat -P ALL shows high %wa time on a single core from an 8 core CPU and I'm trying to figure out what's writing to disk. So how can I figure out what is running on that CPU core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Run `iotop` and will show processes writing on disk.**

Press <kbd>a</kbd> in it to top the most greedy process.

[image]

- **lsof** The following will return a list of all files that are open for writing:**

`lsof | grep -e "[[:digit:]]\+w"`

Answer (score 11):

PSR column in output of :

```
ps -eLF
```

will show you PIDs on each core.

Comment: Thanks! The accepted answer with iotop did not help in my case (a stuck NFS mount), but this answer did, combined with awk to filter by core number: `ps -eLF | awk '$9 == 4'`